# Find the minimal composition from n sets that satisfies the given condition.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

We have N sets of triples, like

```
1. { (4; 0,1), (5 ; 0.3), (7; 0,6) }
2. { (7; 0.2), (8 ; 0.4), (1 ; 0.4) }
...
N. { (6; 0.3), (1; 0.2), (9 ; 0.5) }
```

and need to choose only one pair from each triple, so that the sum of the first members in pair will be minimal, but also we have a condition that sum of the second members in pair must be not less than a given $P$ number.

We can solve this by sorting all possible pair combinations with the sum of their first members ($3 ^ N$ combinations), and in that sorted list choose the first one which also satisfies the second condition.

Could you please help to suggest a better, non trivial solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If the first element is integer, we can process lines one-by-one, maintaining for each $k$ "maximal sum of second elements if sum of first is not more then $k$".

In your example after processing the second line, we will find that we can achieve sum $0.5$ of the second elements with sum $5$ of the firsts, sum $0.7$ with $6$ and sum $1.0$ with $8$.

It is pseudopolynomial - time is proporcinal to $N \cdot \text{sum of first elements}$.

This problem is NP complete. To reduce knapsack with max weight $W$ and min cost $V$ to it, and we transform item with weight $w_i$ and cost $v_i$ to triplet $(w_i, v_i), (0, 0), (0, 0)$. Then we ask if there is family of triplets with sum of second terms been at least $V$ and sum of first at most $W$. Such triplets corresponds to solutions of knapsack problem.

Comment: Thank you too much for your help, I have a question, as I understand if we want to represent this problem as a modified knapsack problem we should do followings: instead of constraining the weight from above, we are constraining it from below, and on each step we are choosing a pair from a triplet, as opposed to deciding whether to put an item into the knapsack or not.   Please, help me to understand how this steps are implemented in your suggested transformation.

Comment: We take a decision version of your problem: can we get sum of first members at most $X$ while having sum of the second at least $P$? Then we say that the first member will represent weight, and the second will represent cost (we want for weight to be small and cost to be big, and in your problem we want first member to be small and second to be big). Taking non-zero pair from $i$-th triplet will correspond to putting $i$-th item into knapsack, and taking zero pair will correspond to not putting it.

Comment: Sorry, one more question, how we indicate that exactly one pair from the initial triplet will be chosen?

Comment: I thought it was part of problem statement that only one pair from each triplet is chosen, wasn't it? And such chooses corresponds to chooses what items to put into backpack.

Comment: exactly one pair from each triplet must be added , but which one we must choose ourselves, so that above mentioned conditions are hold. Sorry if what I wrote doesn't answer your question.

Comment: So, solution for your problem is a choice of pair from each triplet, and solution of knapsack problem is choice of items to put in knapsack. We can reconstruct one from other (though in non-unique way): if we know what items to put into knapsack, we choose non-zero pairs from corresponding triplets and zero triplets from others; it we know what pairs to choose - put into knapsack items corresponding to triplets from which we took non-zero pairs.